# How to find the sum of the first or last number in a range of cells to provide min and max totals?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, range, formula

I hope I can properly describe the problem I'm running into here.

I'm trying to create a formula for the following situation:
I have a spreadsheet that returns a specific dollar range into a cell based on the type of project selected from a drop down box in a previous cell. Example:

| Project | QTY | Range | Total (avg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| floor | 200 | $3-$6 | $900.00 |

The average total is calculated with the following formula:

> =IFERROR(PRODUCT(**QTY CELL***(AVERAGE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(**RANGE CELL**,"$"," "),FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(**RANGE CELL**,"$"," "))-1)+0,RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(**RANGE CELL**,"$"," "),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(**RANGE CELL**,"$"," "))-FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(**RANGE CELL**,"$"," ")))+0))),0)

I want to take ALL of the ranges in the "Range" column and return a minimum total and a maximum total. For example:

| QTY | Range |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | $3-$6 |
| 100 | $8-$35 |

| Min Budget | Max Budget |
| --- | --- |
| $1100 | $4100 |

I guess I could get around it by doing average budget total and simply sum the "Total (avg)" column, but I'm wanting more detail for project budget purposes. If I have to have separate cells that return the sum of min and max budgets for each individual range and then sum those, I wouldn't be too opposed either, but I've tried various ways to do this and wanted to reach out as a last resort to see if someone could help.

Thank you for your time!

EDITED TO ADD:

I did end up getting the following for the minimum budget:

> =IFERROR(SUM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(**RANGE CELL1:RANGE CELLx**,"$"," "),FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(**RANGE CELL1:RANGE CELLx**,"$"," "))-1)+0),0)

However, when there are no numbers in one of the cells, it assumes an error and returns "0." My goal is to make it sum the numbers that are there and ignore the ones that aren't.

Comment: You'd be far better off storing  the range values in two separate cells.

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and simply added in two new columns the sum of each of the min and max of each cell using
> =IFERROR(SUM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(D13,"$"," "),FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(D13,"$"," "))-1)+0),0)
and then "right" for the max
Hid the cells and then summed them in the cells I wanted the totals in. Turned out easier than what I was going for in the end lol

Comment: err, make that
> =IFERROR(PRODUCT(C13*(SUM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(D13,"$"," "),FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(D13,"$"," "))-1)+0))),0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one simple formula solution that will spill both result value.

```
=LET(MINRANGE,VALUE(LEFT(RANGE_RNG,FIND("-",RANGE_RNG)-1)),
MAXRANGE,VALUE(RIGHT(RANGE_RNG,LEN(RANGE_RNG)-FIND("-",RANGE_RNG))),
CHOOSE({"1","2"},SUMPRODUCT(QTY_RNG,MINRANGE),SUMPRODUCT(QTY_RNG,MAXRANGE)))
```

[Input data and Resut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY2Is.png)

Comment: Haven't figure out how to insert the tabulated result